# Build a JSON object in which value should not have quotes using Gson

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a JSON which looks like this:

```
{
"key1": "value1",
"key2": "value2",
"key3": "value3",
"key4": [{
    "key11": {
        "key21": "value21"
    }
}, {
    "key12": "value12"
}]
}
```

and need get JSON for each value in `key4`.

```
{
"key1": "value1",
"key2": "value2",
"key3": "value3",
"key4": {
    "key11": {
        "key21": "value21"
    }
}
}
```

and

```
{
"key1": "value1",
"key2": "value2",
"key3": "value3",
"key4": {
    "key12": "value12"
}
}
```

But one my output is as below:

```
{
"key1": "value1",
"key2": "value2",
"key3": "value3",
"key4": "{\"key11\": {\"key21\": \"value21\"}}"
}
```

I'm using JSON builder and converting a Java object to a JSON object.

```
public class BuildJson {
    private String key1 = "value1";
    private String key2 = "value2";
    private String key3 = "value3"; 
    private String key4;

public BuildJson(String value4) {       
    key4 = value4;
}

public String buildJson(BuildJson bj){      
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
    String new_json = gson.toJson(bj);
    return new_json;        
}
}
```

Initializing constructor and calling `buildJson` method.

```
List <String> key4_object; //holds list of values
for (String i : key4_object){
    BuildJson bj = new BuildJson(i);
    String new_json = bj.buildJson(bj);
    System.out.print(gson.toJson(new_json));
}
```

Since `key4` is of `String` type, it is adding quotes and value is always `String`.

How can I avoid double quote for `key4`?

Comment: But what's wrong with double quotes there?

Comment: Resulting JSON will be returned as response to a web request and It will not display properly. And also key4 is complex nested JSON.

Comment: You just want to return a complex JSON?

Comment: The excepted output which is mentioned above will be returned (one by one based on specific request).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By not making it a `String`. This is the only way; not escaping and double-quoting a `String` would be a wrong and broken behavior.

The problem is that you have JSON with different structures under this key in all 3 cases, so it isn't clear what type it should be instead. You could simply make it `JsonElement key4`:

```
public class BuildJson {
    private String key1 = "value1";
    private String key2 = "value2";
    private String key3 = "value3"; 
    private JsonElement key4;

public BuildJson(Object value4) {       
    key4 = new Gson().toJsonTree(value4);
}

public String buildJson(){      
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
    String new_json = gson.toJson(this);
    return new_json;
}
}
```

And assuming the `String`s in `key4_object` are JSON for objects you want,

```
List<String> key4_object = ...;
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
for (String i : key4_object){
    BuildJson bj = new BuildJson(parser.parse(i));
    String new_json = bj.buildJson();
    System.out.print(gson.toJson(new_json));
}
```

Comment: It is also escaping quotes

Comment: @Naive Are you still passing `String`s to it in loop for `key4_object`? You need to replace them with objects which will produce desired JSON. It isn't clear where `key4_object` comes from in your question or what exactly it contains, but I've edited the answer on one assumption.